# How can I test with RSpec that Rails 3.2 ActionMailer is rendering the correct view template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rspec-rails

I am using [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) and I want to test that my mailer is rendering the correct view template.

```
describe MyMailer do
  describe '#notify_customer' do
    it 'sends a notification' do
      # fire
      email = MyMailer.notify_customer.deliver

      expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).not_to be_empty
      expect(email.from).to include "cs@mycompany.com"

      # I would like to test here something like
      # ***** HOW ? *****
      expect(template_path).to eq("mailers/my_mailer/notify_customer")
    end
  end
end
```

Is this a valid approach? Or shall I do something completely different to that?

**Update**

`MyMailer#notify_customer` might have some logic (e.g. depending on the locale of the customer) to choose different template under different circumstances. It is more or less similar problem with controllers rendering different view templates under different circumstances. With `RSpec` you can write

```
expect(response).to render_template "....."
```

and it works. I am looking for something similar for the mailers.

Comment: why do you want to test that? the view path is defined by the name of the mailer method. There is hardly something that can go wrong here.

Comment: @DominikGoltermann See my update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a step closer to the answer above, since it does test for implicit templates.

```rb
    # IMPORTANT!
    # must copy https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/spec/support/helpers/next_instance_of.rb
    it 'renders foo_mail' do
      allow_next_instance_of(described_class) do |mailer|
        allow(mailer).to receive(:render_to_body).and_wrap_original do |m, options|
          expect(options[:template]).to eq('foo_mail')

          m.call(options)
        end
      end

      body = subject.body.encoded
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand what you're trying to achieve now.

You should be able to test which template is called by setting expectations on your mailer for the `mail` method having been called with particular arguments.

Try this in your test:

```
MyMailer.should_receive(:mail).with(hash_including(:template => 'expected_template'))
```

Comment: No, I do not want to test the content of a particular template. This is the point of a view spec, as you say. Please, see my update. There are cases when an `action_x` renders different view templates based on some kind of logic. I want to test cover this logic.

Comment: I'd like to be able to test this (which template is rendered) too.  Just a quick note on the solution given here: I don't think this works for cases where the template that is rendered is *implicit* (it renders the template matching the action name by default).